# Retraining ResNet-50 for iris flower classification

Tags: tensorflow, residual-networks, iris-dataset

I am trying to retrain ResNet-50 for iris flower classification in tensorflow (TensorFlow version: 2.3.0) using the following code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2, random
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from random import shuffle 
from IPython.display import SVG
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd 
import shutil
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline 
from IPython.display import Image, display
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import os
print(os.listdir("./iris recognition/flowers"))

labels = os.listdir("./iris recognition/flowers")
num_classes = len(set(labels))
IMAGE_SIZE= 224


# Create model
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

# Do not train first layer (ResNet) as it is already pre-trained
model.layers[0].trainable = False

# Compile model
from tensorflow.python.keras import optimizers

sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr = 0.01, decay = 1e-6, momentum = 0.9, nesterov = True)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
train_folder = './iris recognition/flowers'

image_size = 224
data_generator =  tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input,
                                    horizontal_flip=True,
                                    width_shift_range=0.2,
                                    height_shift_range=0.2,
                                    validation_split=0.2)# set validation split

train_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
    train_folder,
    target_size=(image_size, image_size),
    batch_size=10,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='training'
    )
validation_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
    train_folder,
    target_size=(image_size, image_size),
    batch_size=10,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='validation'
    )

NUM_EPOCHS = 70
EARLY_STOP_PATIENCE = 5
from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint

cb_early_stopper = EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss', patience = EARLY_STOP_PATIENCE)
cb_checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath = './working/best.hdf5',
                                  monitor = 'val_loss',
                                  save_best_only = True,
                                  mode = 'auto')
import math

fit_history = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=10,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
#     validation_steps=10,
    epochs=NUM_EPOCHS,
    callbacks=[cb_checkpointer, cb_early_stopper])
model.load_weights("./working/best.hdf5")
```

I tried to change the number of epochs , steps_per_epoch and validation_steps however the model accuracy does not improved as shown in [image: figure1] [image: figure2]

After trying several essais while changing batch size from 32, 64 and 128.For each essai I tried with and without using :

- steps_per_epoch=10.
- sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr = 0.01, decay = 1e-6, momentum = 0.9,
  nesterov = True)

The best accuracy I achieved is 72.29% in which the training was the most stable which was when using batch size=128 as shwon in [image: figure3]

Any suggestions please?!

Comment: Have you tried decreasing the learning rate or increasing the batch size? Your model is fluctuating widely and the lr. or the batch size might be reasons for that.

Comment: I only tried to change the batch size form 24 to 10.

Comment: You could try batch sizes of 32 or 64 (or even 128), this might stabilize the training already.

Comment: Ok I will try it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually, I tried as you said changing with these parameters as follow:  I tried changing the batch size from 32 ,64 and 128 **with sgd** (with and without using steps per epoch) and **without sgd**(with and without using steps per epoch) and the best accuracy I achieved is 72.29%

Comment: Has training become more steady? Have you tried a smaller learning rate as well?

Comment: @Mariusmarten, I have edited the question with the last updates. Considering the learning rate which is in my code **sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr = 0.01, decay = 1e-6, momentum = 0.9, nesterov = True)** I just comment this line and run my code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're defining an optimizer in the line `sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr = 0.01, decay = 1e-6, momentum = 0.9, nesterov = True)` and then not using it, since you compile the model with `optimizer='adam'`. So changing any of the sgd parameters, or even commenting out the line, changes nothing for your model.

you'll need to change to `model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])` to use the `sgd` optimizer object in the model.

Comment: Oh,  I didn't pay attention to that. Ok I will try it.